# PHP return true if URl contains soming after X

Tags: php

i think the answer is realy easy but i cant realy find it.

```
$url = $_REQUEST['pageUrl'] // for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
```

if the url contains something after in this case "/question/ask/" return true
thats realy it i need nothing more only that the url itself is false and when it have a string after "question/ask/ to return true what is the best way ?

I know that this is wrong but the answer must be near to this

```
if ($_REQUEST['pageUrl'] != "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/%")
```

Comment: _the url itself is false_ ?? Huh?

Comment: jea i wannt that only if the url have somting after itself to return true like i tried with "%" i thing i need a placeholder or something and if the placeholder is set return true else return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply search for the text in the URL and see if there is more content after it by comparing the length of the URL to the end of the found text:

```
function urlHasMoreAfter($thisText, $url)
{
    $textPosition = strpos($url, $thisText);

    if (!$textPosition) {
        echo "The text [$thisText] is not in the url";
        return false; // you may want to do something different if the text does not exist in url
    }

    $textLength = strlen($thisText);
    $endOfText = $textPosition + $textLength;

    $endOfURL = strlen($url);

    if ($endOfURL > $endOfText) {
        echo "TRUE - There is more text after [$thisText]";
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo "FALSE - There is NOT more text after [$thisText]";
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Then you would get these results:

```
$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/123';
urlHasMoreAfter('questions/ask', $url); // TRUE

$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';
urlHasMoreAfter('questions/ask', $url); // FALSE

$url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/';
urlHasMoreAfter('questions/ask', $url); // FALSE - Text is not in the url
```

And if you wanted to get what that 'something' was after the specified text, you could easily do this like:

```
$afterText = substr($url, $endOfText + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that way. What you can do is, remove that content from the URL, and check the size of remaining:

```
function checkURL() {
    $url = $_REQUEST['pageUrl'];
    // "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/"
    $url = str_replace("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/", "", $url);
    // ""
    return (strlen($url) > 0);
    // Returns false, if the URL doesn't have anything.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// possible way
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/query=1";//$_REQUEST['pageUrl'];

// check if URL is not empty

if(!empty($url))

{
// ok explode with '/'

$url2 = explode('/', $url);

// get the end

// lets assume we are checking for a view in a method
$found = false;

if(isset($url2[5]) && $url2[5] != "")
{
    $found = true;
}

// this would return true
if($found == true)
{
    // do this
}
```

}

// OR use the .htaccess approach
/*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*/

// now on the php side, you can still use the above approach but adding this

```
$app = isset($_GET['q']) ? explode('/',$_GET['q']) : "";

if(!empty($app))
{
    $found = false;

    // check for url position
    if(isset($app[5]) && !empty($app[5]))
    {
        $found = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Another Approach





   $url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/"; // OR $_REQUEST['pageUrl'];

  // check if URL is not empty

  function checkUrl($url)
 {
if(!empty($url))
{
    // ok explode with '/'
    $url2 = explode('/', $url);


    // get the end
    // lets assume we are checking for a view in a method

    $found = false;

    $end = end($url2);

    if($end != "")
    {
        // should return the value after X if such is found
        // return true
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}